# ezgmail module can't run ezgmail.init() after setting up token.json and credentials.json

Tags: python, json, email

I'm trying to log in to my email using ezgmail. I have already setup my credentials.json and token.json by running quickstart.py, but when I try to run ezgmail.EMAIL_ADDRESS or ezgmail.init() it throws an error.

Here's my code so far:

```
import ezgmail 

print(ezgmail.EMAIL_ADDRESS)
ezgmail.init()
```

Here's the error:

```
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\ddreh\OneDrive\Desktop\emailChecker\windowGUI.py", line 7, in <module>
ezgmail.init()
File "C:\Users\ddreh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ezgmail\__init__.py", line 471, in init
creds = store.get()
File "C:\Users\ddreh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 407, in get
return self.locked_get()
File "C:\Users\ddreh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\file.py", line 54, in locked_get     
credentials = client.Credentials.new_from_json(content)
File "C:\Users\ddreh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 302, in new_from_json
module_name = data['_module']
KeyError: '_module'
```

And here is my current working directory located on my Desktop:

[cwd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bel0d.png)

I'm assuming it's having problems with this '_module' argument but i'm not sure what it is at all. It's returning the EMAIL_ADDRESS variable as false, which should be incorrect as I am logged in according to the token.json. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you loading settings via some JSON file? If so, you might have an error in the formatting in that file.

Comment: The only json files i’ve done anything with are the credentials.json and the token.json. Both of which are auto generated by the quickstart.py which authenticated me earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out after a bit of tinkering. ezgmail and the quickstart.py DO NOT go together. When setting up the ezgmail module you want to make sure you aren't running quickstart.py before because they are two different authentications. You need to get the credentials.json before anything, then run the code:

```
import ezgmail
```

When run the module will open up an internet explorer to authenticate you with your google project. Go through the authentication flow and you should be good to go. If you've already used quickstart.py and generated a token.json you can delete it and run 'import ezgmail' to reauthenticate yourself.